# Javascript: in an HTML table, how to select part of text (matching some regex) from one column, and move it to the next one?

Tags: javascript, regex, html-table, greasemonkey

I have an HTML table which eg, 2 columns
and the data in the 1st one are like this: (the 2nd is empty -I use _ as "empty"-)

```
1 (5%)  |  _  
2 (10%) |  _  
3 (15%) |  _
```

which, for reference is:

```
<table id="my_table" >
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1 (5%)</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2 (10%)</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3 (15%)</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want (in javascript -greasemonkey- ) for each cell of that column,
to move the number which is inside the parentheses (=with regex matching),
to the cell next to it,  i.e. to the 2nd column.
Therefore the table will be converted to

```
1 | 5%  
2 | 10%  
3 | 15%
```

which is:

```
<table id="my_table" >
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>5%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>10%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>15%</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: I would start by iterating over the table's [*rows* collection](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/tabular-data.html#dom-table-rows), then use each row's [*cells* collection](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/tabular-data.html#dom-tr-cells) to get the content of the first cell, then use that to write new content to the first and second cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some simple functions to iterate over the table's row and do what you want. The *modTable* function assumes an id is passed, but it could be a reference to the table instead.

```
function modTable(id) {
  var table = document.getElementById(id);
  var row, rows = table.rows;
  var cell, cells, text, t0, t1;

  for (var i=0, iLen=rows.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    row = rows[i];
    text = getText(row.cells[0]);

    // Get just leading digits
    t0 = text.replace(/\D+.*/,'');

    // Get just the part in brackets
    t1 = text.replace(/(^.+\()|(\).*$)/g,'');

    // Set new values
    setText(row.cells[0], t0);
    setText(row.cells[1], t1);
  }
}

// Simple helpers for modern and older browsers
// Get textContent of an element
function getText(el) {
  return el.textContent || el.innerText || '';
}

// Set the textContent of an element
function setText(el, text) {
  if (typeof el.textContent == 'string') {
    el.textContent = text;
  } else if (typeof el.innerText == 'string') {
    el.innerText = text;
  }
}
```

It can be called from a button:

```
<button onclick="modTable('my_table');">Modify the table</button>
```